Error update value when using DatePicker of PrimeVue v4 in project Vue + Inertia + laravel
I am a newbie in VueJS and I have a problem when I choose the first value of the DatePicker it works correctly, but when I update it by choosing another year it has an error.error when change year](https://i.sstatic.net/TypQBjJj.png)
and here is my record for this issue
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a7K3F2lqbSyxBW2JeKZI0V2mL0HPPiLI/view?usp=sharing
and my code using the DatePicker from PrimeVue v4
<template>
  <Box>
    <DatePicker name="birthday" placeholder="Select date" v-model="date" showIcon fluid />
  </Box>
</template>

<script setup>
import DatePicker from 'primevue/datepicker';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const date = ref()
</script>

Anyone can help me solve this issue.
